# ingress-nginx how to add /app in front of every paths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Originally, User can visit the `"example.com/dashboard/xxxx"` and because some reason my team want to add /app in front of every path we have.

For example:
/dashboard/xxxx -> /app/dashboard/xxxx
/auth/signup -> /app/auth/signup

What I want to achieve

1. When User visit the `"example.com/app/dashboard/xxxx"` They will see the content from `"example.com/dashboard/xxxx"` but the url still maintain `"example.com/app/dashboard/xxxx"`

**The frontend guys already build the image and both env use the same image.
**
And I have two environment.

The first env I use **nginx** and **haproxy** which I already achieved the goal.
I add the location block into frontend nginx config

Here is my original config (I still have different config for other path like /dashboard, /pdf-builder ...)

```
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name _;

    limit_conn limitperip 10;
  limit_req zone=ratelimit burst=10 nodelay;

  index index.html;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  send_timeout 10;

  client_body_timeout 10;
  client_header_timeout 10;
  client_max_body_size 100K;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
  add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block";
  #add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer";

  if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|DELETE)$) {
    return 444;
  }

  location /auth  {
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    alias /var/www/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }


  location = / {
    return 200 'OK';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }

  location ~ /\. { deny all; return 404;  }

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/ltv2-auth.access.log combined_ssl;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/ltv2-auth.error.log info;
}
```

And I add this

```
location ^~ /app/ {
    rewrite ^/app(/.*)$ $1/ break;
    proxy_pass https://"my load-balancer's ip";
  }
```

For haproxy part.
I only add this line

`acl to_auth url_beg -i /app/auth/`

```
  acl to_auth url_beg -i /auth/
  acl to_auth url_beg -i /app/auth/ # <- new line I added.
  use_backend frontend_servers_auth if to_auth
```

and everything works normally.

---

But the second env I still don't know how to do...
I use helm-chart to deploy my main app and ingress-nginx with k8s.

Here is my main app's **values.yml**

I only capture the code I think it's related

```
  services:
    - name: backend
      port: 3000
      prefix: /api
    - name: admin
      port: 3000
      prefix: /admin
  podReadinessProbe:
    path: /api/v2/ping
    port: 3000
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 300m
      memory: 2Gi

frontend:
  fullname: frontend
  replicaCount: 1
  targetPort: 8080
  image:
    name: ltv2
    tag: 23.12.1-83-g5ab246b
  serviceType: ClusterIP
  services:
    - name: auth
      port: 8001
      prefix: /auth
    - name: builder
      port: 8002
      prefix: /pdf-builder
    - name: payment
      port: 8003
      prefix: /payment
    - name: dashboard
      port: 8004
      prefix: /dashboard
    
  podReadinessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /
      port: 8080

nginx:
  frontend:
    site_enabled:
      conf: |
        server {
          listen 8080;
          server_name  _;
          
          location ^~ /dashboard/ {
            alias /var/www/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
          }
          location ^~ /payment/ {
            alias /var/www/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
          }
          location ^~ /pdf-builder/ {
            alias /var/www/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
          }
          location ^~ /auth/ {
            alias /var/www/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
          }
          location = /dashboard {
            alias /var/www;
            try_files /index.html /dev/null =404;
          }
          location = / {
            return 200 'OK';
            add_header Content-Type text/plain;
          }
        }
```

and my **ingress.yml** in the same main app repo. It's not in the ingress-nginx controller

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "helm_legal_templates.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "helm_legal_templates.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}

spec:
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: backend
      port:
        number: 3000
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        {{- range .Values.backend.services }}
        - path: {{ .prefix }}
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: {{ .name }}
              port:
                number: {{ .port }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- range .Values.frontend.services }}
        - path: {{ .prefix }}
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: {{ .name }}
              port:
                number: {{ .port }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

I try to add the same location block in the values.yml and add /app to  `- path: {{ .prefix }}`in the ingress.yml. but with no luck and got 406 error.

Any advice is welcome and thanks!!

I want to achieve the same result like my first env.